# How to make a JAR that opens CMD and displays text or asks for input?

Tags: java, jar

The class I have asks for input (NON GUI), but how do I make it a Jar, which would go to the CMD and ask for input?

I used IntelliJ IDEA to extract the class into a JAR and when I run it nothing happens

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: *I used IntelliJ IDEA to extract the class into a JAR* Not an accurate description of what you should be doing. "Build executable jar with IntelliJ" would be